# Doubly Linked List Insert After Function

Tags: c

I already posted something similar before but this is another part of a problem that I'm having and I would appreciate your ideas and if you can help me fix my mistake.

As stated on my title i'm building a Doubly Linked List and I would like to know if my function insert_after works or not. When I run the full code I can't insert after the value that I chose which is why I'm posting this. Please let me know if I'm not clear or if this question is wrongly asked. I'm new in C and just need your help understanding.

This is my struct:

```
 struct node
 {
  char data[100];
  struct node *previous;  // Points to the previous node
  struct node *next;   // Points out to the next node
 }*head, *last;
```

This is my function to insert after a the chosen word:

```
 char insert_after(char words[99], char loc[99])
 {
  struct node *temp, *var, *temp1;
  var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  strncpy(var->data, words,100);

  if (head==NULL)
  {
    head=var;
    head->previous=NULL;
    head->next=NULL;

  }
  else
  {
    temp=head;
    while ((temp!=NULL) && (temp->data!=loc))
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if (temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n %s not presented at list\n", loc);
    }
    else
    {
        temp1=temp->next;
        temp->next=var;
        var->previous=temp;
        var->next=temp1;
        temp1->previous=var;
    }
  }
  last=head;
  while (last->next!=NULL)
  {
    last=last->next;
  }
  return 0;// take it out after
 }
```

And this is my main: --> Case 3 is my problem

```
 int main()
 {
char loc[99];
char words[99];
int i, dat;

head=NULL;

printf("Select the choice of operation on link list");
printf("\n1.) Insert At Begning\n2.) Insert At End\n3.) Insert At Middle");
printf("\n4.) Delete From End\n5.) Reverse The Link List\n6.) Display List\n7.)Exit");

   while(1)
  {
    printf("\n\n Enter the choice of operation you want to do ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            printf("Enter a word you want to insert in the 1st node ");
            scanf(" %s",words);

            insert_beginning(words);
            display();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            printf("Enter a word you want to insert in the last node ");
            scanf(" %s",words);
            insert_end(words);
            display();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            printf("After which data you want to insert your new data ");
            scanf(" %s",words);

            printf("Enter the data you want to insert in list ");
            scanf(" %s",loc);

            insert_after(words, loc);
            display();
            break;
        }
```

I didn't put the full code because it's pretty long which is why i posted the important stuff.
Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem:

```
while ((temp!=NULL) && (temp->data!=loc))
```

temp->data != loc is not comparing strings, it just compares pointer addresses.
You could use strcmp or a similar string comparision function. strcmp returns non-zero if 
the two parameters differ.

```
while ((temp!=NULL) && (strcmp(temp->data, words))
```

Note that it is `words` that is to compared to the values in the list as `words` is the value that `loc` is to be inserted after.

If you use char arrays as the parameters to insert_after function care will be needed to ensure that the entire length of the array is initialised correctly.

Note that a check on the following node is necessary in case there is only one node in the list (the following node will be NULL in this case).

```
char insert_after(char *words, char *loc)
 {
  struct node *temp, *var;
  var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  strcpy(var->data, loc);

  if (head==NULL)
  {
    head=var;
    head->previous=NULL;
    head->next=NULL;

  }
  else
  {
    temp=head;
    while ((temp!=NULL) && (strcmp(temp->data, words)))
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if (temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n %s not presented at list\n", words);
    }
    else
    {
        struct node * followingNode = temp->next;
        temp->next=var;
        var->previous=temp;
        var->next= followingNode;
        if (followingNode)
        followingNode->previous = var;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems that I can only add the same string that I already have in my linked list.
so if i already inputed: ->hey->hello and i want to add another new word after hey i cant i can only input the words that are already stored in my list

Comment: amazing it works perfectly I will try and understand more about how you did it.

Comment: okay very new to this. I never understood your "followingNode" assignment. also for this specific function can I use the same theory for deleting a data in my list?

Comment: `followingNode` is what in your code is `temp1`. It's the node after the one being inserted. Yes the deletion function will be similar to the insert function.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `memcmp` or, better yet, `strcmp` for string comparison instead of `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

### Issues

1. `char words[99]` has 99 elements but you're allowing up to 100 here, `strncpy(var->data, words,100);`.  That may cause a problem if `words` is not `'\0'` terminated.  You could unintentially write `word[99]` to `var->data` which shouldn't be allowed.  Change the statement to this:

   ```
   strncpy(var->data, words, 99);
   var->data[99] = '\0'; // In case words wasn't a string
   ```
2. You cannot compare strings like this, `temp->data!=loc`.  You're actually comparing addresses.  Change this line to the following:

   ```
   while((temp != NULL) && (strcmp(temp->data, loc) != 0));
   ```
3. `var->next=temp1` is incorrect.  We're at the end of the list so this line should be rewritten as follows:

   ```
   var->next = NULL;
   ```

Comment: thanks i'll try it out and i'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for explaining really helps me understand

Comment: i'm having one last problem. The fact that I set my var->next to NULL it deletes everything there is on the list after the word i'm inserting. any ideas? how can i keep the words in my list ?